# Drag-and-drop is worth to use with visionOS?

Tags: swiftui, visionos

Our existing app uses drag-and-drop a lot, when running in visionOS Simulator of course it works, as I am using cursor and mouse on my computer.

What will happen in real device? How drag and drop will work? What if some of the target drop view is invisible? In traditional environment DropDelegate has a `dropEntered` method. When cursor moves over it, it can highlight the existence of it.

Will this work in the same way in visionOS? as my eyes cross scene invisible drop views can be highlighted?

Maybe it is better to us a normal tap based interaction, let user pinch with finger and mark somehow "source" and "destination" views?